# Cannot open Tor Browser using Terminal

Tags: tor-browser-bundle, directory, ubuntu

I recently extracted tor-browser-linux64-6.0a4_en-US.tar.xz on a mounted drive. And tried to start the browser.

The Browser didn't open due to not recognizing the .desktop file which starts the Browser. Later, I was advised to copy and paste it in home directory.

And after pasting it in home directory, it no more shows permission problem or recognizing problem regarding the .desktop file by bash but now, it is showing permission problem in execdesktop file in Browser directory of Tor Browser's root directory.

```
user@user's-desktop:~$ cd tor-browser_en-US
user@user's-desktop:~/tor-browser_en-US$ ./start-tor-browser.desktop
/usr/bin/env: ./Browser/execdesktop: Permission denied
```

Answer (score 3):

The `desktop` file doesn't work in any case. However Tor comes with a shell script. You can execute it and Tor Browser will start. It is located in the `Browser/` subdirectory:

```
tor-browser_en-US/Browser/start-tor-browser
```

Comment: when try to use start-tor-browser in Browser directory, it shows  -- user@user's-desktop:~$ tor-browser_en-US/Browser/start-tor-browser
bash: tor-browser_en-US/Browser/start-tor-browser: Permission denied

Comment: It works and opens tor browser. But how can I fix it using starter command?

Answer (score 1):

on Ubuntu 18.10 it works now ... just get into dir once download is expanded

```
cd ~/src/tor-browser-linux64-8.0.3_en-US/tor-browser_en-US
./start-tor-browser.desktop --help
```

which suggests you issue

```
./start-tor-browser.desktop  --register-app
```

> Launching './Browser/start-tor-browser --detach --register-app'...
>   Tor Browser has been registered as a desktop app for this user in ~/.local/share/applications/

now you have registered the app so its searchable + launchable from dash so

```
Show applications -> tor
```

so launching from dash is possible ... from terminal just cat out above mentioned file `./start-tor-browser.desktop` and look for line with `Exec` which looks like

```
Exec=sh -c '"/home/ota/src/tor-browser-linux64-8.0.3_en-US/tor-browser_en-US/Browser/start-tor-browser" --detach || ([ !  -x "/home/ota/src/tor-browser-linux64-8.0.3_en-US/tor-browser_en-US/Browser/start-tor-browser" ] && "$(dirname "$*")"/Browser/start-tor-browser --detach)' dummy %k
```

so to launch directly from terminal issue

```
/home/ota/src/tor-browser-linux64-8.0.3_en-US/tor-browser_en-US/Browser/start-tor-browser
```

adjust your downloaded dir as mine is `/home/ota/src/tor-browser-linux64-8.0.3_en-US/`

Answer (score -3):

This message appears because you didn't gave executable permission to those files
 now you just go the /browser folder & make those files executable by typing ""chmod +x *"(without any quotes).

Now you will be able to run Tor Browser by executing "start-tor-browser.desktop" or "tor.desktop" any of these files.
[image: making executable tor files]

Comment: no `chmod +x *` is not a good solution.